# Unable to add pyinstaller path

Tags: path

I have installed 'pyinstaller' using pip and it was installed in the following path
Location: c:\users\srinivasbolem\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages

I added this path to system environment variables, still it shows "Pyinstaller is not recognized as internal or external command"

[message in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egV0i.png)

I tried to add the path for pyinstaller, but no use
In terminal I could see version of python and pip, but when I tried to look versions of pandas and pyinstaller it throws the error mentioned above.

The file path I saw on web, and mine are very different, I don't why?
But all the libraries are working fine.
[screenshot of the mentioned problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G90FB.png)